# Datetime picker 00-0000-00 output

Tags: php, datetimepicker

**I tried all the suggestion I read here but still it save as 00-0000-00 I hope someone will help me. The codes below will show the htm and php. the last part is the php.**  any help will highly appreciated

my code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
<script>
$(function() {
$( "#my_date" ).datepicker({ 
dateFormat: "MM/dd/yy",
defaultDate: "January/01/1970",
minDate: "January/01/1925",
maxDate: "December/31/2011",
changeMonth: true,
changeYear: true,
yearRange: "1925:2011",
onClose: function(dateText, inst) {
    var validDate = $.datepicker.formatDate( "MM/dd/yy",     $('#my_date').datepicker('getDate'));
        $('#my_date').datepicker('setDate', validDate);
    }
});
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form action="" method="post" id="myform">
<input name="my_date" id="my_date" type="text" value="January/01/2016" />
<tr><td><label>Add New Election</label></td>
<td><input type="text" name="idelection" value="" style="width:250px; height:34px; border:1px solid #336666;"/></td>
<td><input type="text" name="electitle" value="" style="width:250px; height:34px; border:1px solid #336666;"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td align="center"><input type="submit" value="ADD" name="submit"/></td>
 </tr>
 </form>
 </body>
 </html>
```

**The php part **

```
  <?php
  include "connection.php";
  session_start();
  $con = db();

 if(isset($_POST["submit"])){

$id = isset($_POST['idelection']) ? $_POST['idelection'] : '';
$title = isset($_POST['electitle']) ? $_POST['electitle'] : '';
$date1 = $_POST['my_date'];
$date = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$date1);
$new_date = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($date));




$sql = 'INSERT INTO election_time (elec_id,elec_date) VALUES ("'.$_POST['idelection'].'","$new_date")';
$sql2 = 'INSERT INTO election (elec_id,elec_title) VALUES ("'.$_POST['idelection'].'","'.$_POST['electitle'].'")';

$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
$result2 = mysqli_query($con,$sql2);

if(!$result && !$result2){
die("Error on mysql query".mysqli_error());
}
}


?>
```

Answer (score 4):

If you'd bothered doing any kind of basic debugging:

```
php > var_dump(strtotime('January/01/1970'));
bool(false)
```

Your date format is NOT something `strtotime()` recognizes, so it fails, returns boolean `FALSE`, which you then blindly insert into the the `date()`, where it is treated as integer `0`, so your date is actually the Unix epoch, `Jan 1, 1970`.

And note that your code is wide open to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com).

Comment: For details of the date formats that strtotime() will recognise, they are [documented here](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php)

Comment: sorry I'm new in php I don't get you.

Comment: your date picker is generating date strings that php doesn't recognize, you never bothered checking if anything failed, and simply assumed success. since there were failures, and you didn't check for failure, those failures propagated and caused further failures.

Comment: Ahh so what is the right function to use to store date in database

Comment: you use a mysql date/datetime type, and use mysql's native date-as-string format: `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss`. how you present those dates to users as readable text has absolutely nothing to do with how you store them internally. you always use native formatting, and convert for output as necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Just do one thing in your JS. If possible change your date format to this

```
dateFormat: "MM-dd-yy",



$(function() {
    $( "#my_date" ).datepicker({ 
    dateFormat: "MM-dd-yy",
    defaultDate: "January/01/1970",
    minDate: "January/01/1925",
    maxDate: "December/31/2011",
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    yearRange: "1925:2011",
    onClose: function(dateText, inst) {
        var validDate = $.datepicker.formatDate( "MM-dd-yy",$('#my_date').datepicker('getDate'));
        $('#my_date').datepicker('setDate', validDate);
}
    });
});
```

Comment: still the same, nothing happen. Thank you though